# MediaElement.js audio player volume control misaligned in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I'm using the MediaElement.js WordPress plugin for a simple audio player. In Chrome the volume control is displaying under the player, indented from the right. The volume control is correctly positioned in Safari and Firefox (I haven't had an opportunity to test it in IE).

Here is a link to one of the pages where the problem is occurring: http://www.coffeecrossroads.com/coffee-and-the-arts/music/bob-dylan-one-more-cup-of-coffee/

My hope is that this can easily be fixed with CSS, but I haven't yet figured out how. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It is displaying correctly for me.  Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Not seeing it, bro: http://i.imgur.com/OWzJzri.png

Comment: Thanks, Michael and Joseph. Apparently its just a problem on Chrome for Mac. [Chrome Mac Screenshot](http://www.coffeecrossroads.com/audio-player-misaligned.png) Odd, too, because that's the browser that I used to develop the site and it looked perfect until a couple of hours ago. No conflicts that I've been able to isolate either.

Comment: Quick update: This problem is no longer occurring. But I don't know why. I played around with the CSS for the audio player but nothing worked. So I left it alone for a while. When I came back to it a couple of hours later, it looked fine. Keeping fingers crossed ...

Comment: This problem has now reappeared, as suddenly as it disappeared. Again, it's in Chrome on Mac only (as far as I know -- I haven't tested every browser). See [www.coffeecrossroads.com](http://www.coffeecrossroads.com).

Comment: Another similar problem: in Opera for Mac, the Play and Mute buttons are too large and partially cut off. This is a great player -- but it would be even better if the display were consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue. It seems that ChiChou's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583839/4327972) was finally used. If you update mediaElement at least to the version of the 31/08/2014 (2.15.1). You should be fine!
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/483
(Posting this because I've seen it's not yet fixed on your website)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with mediaelement and Chrome on a Mac. After carefully going through all of my CSS to find the issue, I discovered that I had my text size reduced, and this was causing it to break. I adjusted my text size to the default with CMD-0 and that moved everything back into alignment.

Comment: I don't think this was the cause of the problem for me. I've resized the text a few times and it hasn't affected the problem. But I say "was" because, like the first time this happened, it just "fixed itself" after a while. It's good now, but I'd still like to know why it's been happening.