# mediaelement.js volume control messed when increasing browser zoom

Tags: css, zooming, mediaelement.js

Media Element 2.12.0

This happens only in FF and Chrome (and not in IE or Opera). After navigating to site content which has media element player, even to Media Element front page http://mediaelementjs.com/ there is a player.

When the browser zoom is set to Normal (usually by pressing Ctrl+0) it looks OK.

When the zoom is increased (by pressing Ctrl++ or Ctrl+ scrolling mouse wheel) then the volume control is placed below the whole element.

[image: Screenshot of MEJS website]

The above screenshot was made at zoom one level larger from normal.

Is there a method to make it look good in all browser zooms?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, FF 22.0 Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: This bug has been around for at least a year. https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/483

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the children of **div.mejs-controls** overflowed when scaling the page, but it isn't a CSS case. The size of **div.mejs-time-rail** is generated by Javascript dynamically. (https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/mep-player.js#L845)

[image: Inspect Elements]

I found a trick that can simply solve the problem, which is to decrease the width of div.mejs-time-rail by 1px.

So here I got a quick fix. In mep-player.js, line 845(https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/mep-player.js#L845), modify following

```
total.width(railWidth - (total.outerWidth(true) - total.width()));
```

to

```
total.width(railWidth - (total.outerWidth(true) - total.width()) - 1);
```

Comment: Please ignore previous comment - this seems to be the best solution, you can also monkey-patch this instead of changing the mejs code.

Comment: I had a very specific application for this where i knew the exact size every time, so I set .mejs-time-rail { width: 196px !important; } and it worked great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in the file mediaelement-and-player.js by altering the following lines

```
line 2705 insert **- 40**
// fit the rail into the remaining space
railWidth = t.controls.width() - usedWidth - 40 - (rail.outerWidth(true) - rail.width());

line 2713 change to
total.width(railWidth - (total.outerWidth(true) - total.width()) - 5);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change in your css and set the width like

```
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" style="width: 440px; height: 30px;">
<div class="mejs-inner" style="width:100%;">
<div class="mejs-mediaelement">
```

and check. hope this will help you.

Comment: In what circumstance does adding `width:100%` help? I don't see a difference.

Comment: in div 'mep_0', I changed the width from 380px to 440px and apply the width=100% in div 'mejs-inner. you can check your output with the increment/decrement of witdth in mep_0 dive. hope this will help you.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the other answer, just expanding the player instead of making inside smaller.  It still doesn't look right on all the zoom levels.

Comment: Actually when you are zooming, the width of div 'mep_0' doesn't changed and it gets the 380px width, you have to check which css is appling here. and one more change I noticed that if I change the width of div "div{class='grid_5 push_1'}" equal to 400px and the 'mep_0' width = 100%, then its work here. once you have to try this

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. It seems that ChiChou's answer was finally used. If you update mediaElement at least to the version of the 31/08/2014 (2.15.1). You should be fine!
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/483